# How dangerous javascripts really are?

Tags: javascript

I've watched this video, and what this guy says is that
with javascript its easy to create a worm that steals your information
also that javascript will continue to execute even tho you closed the tab
of the infected site , on the other tabs. Even after closing the browser
it will save itself in cache only to load itself next time you open the browser.
Are javascripts really that dangerous? Is it worth using NoScript?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT4YJn7oVI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You slightly missed the point of the video. Its main message is not *"Javascript is dangerous"* it is **"Anonymous proxy servers are dangerous!"**

The attack in the video you posted is mostly based on getting the target to use a malicious proxy server. Using a proxy server is a conscious choice the user makes, and using a proxy which is not trustworthy is a very bad idea. A proxy server is able to eavesdrop and manipulate anything you read (or post) on the web. That also gives them the ability to inject Javascript code into websites and monitor your activity on them.

When you want to be safe from the attack presented in that video, don't use any proxy servers not operated by someon you trust, that simple.

But let's get on your actual question: **"Is Javascript dangerous per-se?"**

When the browsers javascript engine **works as designed**, then Javascript is pretty safe. Conceptually, Javascript is not able to access any other tabs except the one it is embedded in. Persistent javascript which runs after the tab is closed is also impossible.

However, all browsers had bugs in the past which could be exploited to override some of these restrictions under some circumstances.

Regarding whether or not using NoScript is an option: NoScript can protect you from *some* browser-based exploits, but not all. There are a lot of other exploits which target other sub-systems of the browser. The main motivation to use NoScript is to protect your sanity from websites which abuse Javascript for inversive advertising or other annoyances.

Comment: I get that, but it doesn't have to be a "anonymous proxy server" ,  any website of any content could have that malicious javascript payload, it doesn't have to be a proxy server, since what he showed is that even if you his proxy only once you are infected for ever.

Comment: @user45848 I think you are referring to that caching thing. This scenario benefits from the fact that some website authors load common Javascript libraries (like jQuery) from 3rd party websites. When you visit two websites which use the same URL to load the library, the browser won't redownload it the second time and use the same copy from cache, even when it isn't using the same proxy anymore. However, the infection won't be "forever" - it will only persist until the cache entry expired.

Comment: You might want to argument "But he set the `Expires:` time to FOREVER!" - yes, but cache expiry times are just a recommendation for the web browser. Usually browsers have a fixed hard-drive quota for cache. When it's full it works as a first-in-first-out queue. When your browser has a 400MB cache quota, it will start discarding cached data after 400MB of internet activity, even when its expiry time isn't reached yet.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript itself is simply a programming language and is not inherently dangerous.

However, the first immutable law says:

> Law #1: If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your computer, it's not solely your computer anymore.

So it is a good general rule to be careful about running arbitrary pieces of code you find on the Internet. Browser manufacturers go to great lengths to protect you from malicious code but they can't catch everything.

You can turn JavaScript (and Java and Flash and Silverlight and so on) off very simply, but this means a much worse experience when using the Internet.

So a solution like NoScript is a good compromise, allowing you to selectively enable Javascript only on web sites you trust.

As with all security questions it comes down to you making an informed choice about what risk you are prepared to accept and whether the cost of a control like NoScript is worth it.